# Animating cells in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a section in UITableView that once I click on it 4 animated cells drop down, however, the problem is that when they drop down they go down past the view (screen), and you can't see them unless you scroll down. How would I make it so that once the section is clicked that it push the entire view up revealing all the cells in the drop down menu? Here's my code:

```
- (void) sectionOpened : (NSInteger) section{

    SectionInfo *array = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
    array.open = YES;

    NSInteger count = [array.category.list count];
    NSMutableArray *indexPathToInsert = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = 0; i<count;i++)
    {
        [indexPathToInsert addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:section]];
    }

    NSMutableArray *indexPathsToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSInteger previousOpenIndex = self.openSectionIndex;
    if (previousOpenIndex != NSNotFound)
    {
        SectionInfo *sectionArray = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:previousOpenIndex];
        sectionArray.open = NO;
        NSInteger counts = [sectionArray.category.list count];
        [sectionArray.sectionView toggleButtonPressed:FALSE];
        for (NSInteger i = 0; i<counts; i++)
        {
            [indexPathsToDelete addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:previousOpenIndex]];
        }
    }
    UITableViewRowAnimation insertAnimation;
    UITableViewRowAnimation deleteAnimation;
    if (previousOpenIndex == NSNotFound || section < previousOpenIndex)
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
    }
    else
    {
        insertAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationBottom;
        deleteAnimation = UITableViewRowAnimationTop;
    }

    [atableView beginUpdates];

    [atableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathToInsert withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    [atableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToDelete withRowAnimation:deleteAnimation];


    [atableView endUpdates];

    self.openSectionIndex = section;

}
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using this tableView method?

```
- (void)scrollToRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath atScrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition animated:(BOOL)animated
```

So you could try.

```
[atableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPathToInsert atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Did you do it after the call to endUpdates?